# how to filter for results for which a property has a value contained in array X

Tags: rethinkdb

Say I've got a dynamic array A of values `[x,y,z]`. 
I want to return all results for which property P has a value that exists in A.

I could write some recursive filter that concatenates 'or's for each value in A, but it's extremely clunky.

Any other out-of-the-box way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` command in conjunction with the [`reduce`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/reduce/) and [`contains`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/contains/) command to accomplish this.

**Example**

Let's say you have the following documents:

```
{
  "id":  "41e352d0-f543-4731-b427-6e16a2f6fb92" ,
  "property": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}, {
  "id":  "a4030671-7ad9-4ab9-a21f-f77cba9bfb2a" ,
  "property": [ 5, 6, 7 ]
}, {
  "id":  "b0694948-1fd7-4293-9e11-9e5c3327933e" ,
  "property": [ 2, 3, 4 ]
}, {
  "id":  "4993b81b-912d-4bf7-b7e8-e46c7c825793" ,
  "property": [ "b" ,"c" ]
}, {
  "id":  "ce441f1e-c7e9-4a7f-9654-7b91579029be" ,
  "property": [ "a" , "b" , "c" ]
}
```

From these sequence, you want to get all documents that have either `"a"` or `1` in their `property` property. You can write a query that returns a chained [`contains`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/contains/) statement using `reduce`.

```
r.table('30510212')
  // Filter documents
  .filter(function (row) { 
    // Array of properties you want to filter for
    return r.expr([ 1, 'a' ]) 
      // Insert `false` as the first value in the array
      // in order to make it the first value in the reduce's left
      .insertAt(0, false) 
      // Chain up the `contains` statement
      .reduce(function (left, right) {
        return left.or(row('property').contains(right));
      });
  })
```

**Update: Better way to do it**

Actually, you can use 2 `contains` to execute the same query. This is shorter and probably a bit easier to understand.

```
r.table('30510212')
  .filter(function (row) {
    return row('property').contains(function (property) {
      return r.expr([ 1, 'a' ]).contains(property);
    })
  })
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm comfortable with reduce, etc. but still looks pretty involved. Thanks though